# Parallel Shared Container in datastage Job

Tags: datastage

I created a Datastage Parallel job with Parallel Shared Container. The job was working fine. I did not make any change to the job. Suddenly the job has started failing with below error since 1 day:

> main_program: Failed to create collation sequence from IBM InfoSphere
>   DataStage Enterprise Edition 9.1.0.6791 . Failed to create collation
>   sequence from IBM InfoSphere DataStage Enterprise Edition 9.1.0.6791.

Has anyone has faced similar issue?

Please help and let me know for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned error came due to incorrect NLS in the present transformers in the Container. I changed the NLS to ProjectDefault(OFF) and the issue got solved.